# Understanding Linux module code snippet

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am interpreting a generated intermediate code of a linux kernel module. But i am unable to understand the following line of code of `pci_set_dma_mask`

```
if ((err = pci_set_dma_mask(pdev, (((32) == 64) ? ~0ULL : ((1ULL<<(32))-1))))) {

          (void)((NETIF_MSG_PROBE & nic->msg_enable) && printk("<3>" "e100" ": " "%s: %s: "
                   "No usable DMA configuration, aborting.\n", nic->netdev->name, func));
}
```

My understanding is that, since 32 != 64, `((1ULL<<(32))-1)` will execute. But what kind of value is `1ULL`? What is happening internally when we left shift `1ULL` 32 times?. And can someone provide some code samples to understand this? Thanks in advance

Comment: `ULL` just makes the constant `unsigned long long` (i.e. pretty much gurantees it will be at least 32 bits). The shift value is just `(2^32)-1` (i.e. 31 'ones'). The `(32) == 64` part looks like a macro replacement, or generated code

Comment: Okay. but what is `1ULL`  / `0ULL` ?

Comment: That's a divide-by-zero exception.

Comment: `~0ULL` is the 1's complement of zero (i.e. all ones) as an `unsigned long long`. `1ULL` should now be obvious

Comment: This function `((32) == 64) ? ~0ULL : ((1ULL<<(32))-1)` is actually a macro `DMA_BIT_MASK()` that is pretty straitforward to get. @kdopen, see above.

Answer (score 0):

The redundant parentheses and the trivial condition `(32) == 64` show that this is generated code, possibly the result of running the preprocessor. That condition tests whether something is 32-bit or 64-bit and the code has been generated for a system where that thing is 32-bit.

On a 64-bit system, the value `~0ULL` is used. With the `ULL` suffix, the constant is of type `unsigned long long`, which is a 64-bit type on all platforms that the Linux kernel supports (standard C specifies that `unsigned long long` is 64-bit or larger but almost all systems have it as exactly 64 bits). The `~` operator takes the bitwise complement, so the result is the number 2<sup>64</sup>-1, i.e. a 64-bit constant whose binary representation is all-bits-one. In hexadecimal, that's `0xffffffffffffffff`.

The reason the code uses `~0ULL` and not `~0` is that in `~0`, the constant `0` is an `int`, which is a 32-bit type on all platforms that the Linux kernel support. The `~` operator applies to this would yield a 32-bit value with all-bits-one, i.e. `0xffffffff` in hexadecimal, i.e. the number number 2<sup>32</sup>-1. When converted to a 64-bit value, the numerical value remains the same — *not* an all-64-bits-one constant.

On a 32-bit system, the code uses `1ULL<<(32))-1`. First `1ULL` is a 64-bit value; `1ULL << 32` shifts it left by 32, which means multiplying the numerical value by 2<sup>32</sup>, which yields the number 2<sup>32</sup>, or in hexadecimal `0x100000000`. Subtracting 1 yields 2<sup>32</sup>, i.e. `0xffffffff` (an all-32-bits-one constant).

Doing the operations on an `unsigned long long` is necessary here too, because a left shift by 32 is not defined for 32-bit values. Standard C says that `x << 32` is undefined behavior if the type of `x` is a 32-bit type or less. In practice, on many systems, the processor instruction for shifting on a 32-bit type takes a shift amount in the range 0…31, and `1 << 32` would be compiled to the same code as `1 << 0` (wrapping modulo 32), yielding 1 instead of 2<sup>32</sup>.